# Want to connect to smb server using spark and load the files from that server in spark.. Lets say

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Let's Say :
I have a location like smb://cluster/something/ 
I want to connect to this location and want to load the files from that folder into spark.

Is there any way possible, I can do or Spark supports only hdfs system ??

Comment: @Srinivas thanks for the answer but did not get much clarity, custom data source means , which will connect to smb using Spark ? this is even my question as well . if you can give one example ?

Comment: @Srinivas I know how to connect it using java I also want to know how to process/load using Spark that is what even my question, do you have answer for that?

Comment: @Srinivas it is mostly excel file

Comment: I do not want to bring the file to my edge node or hdfs that is simple , my question is that can we connect to some server using sbm protocol and get that file and directly load it using spark without pushing it to any hdfs system.

Answer (score -1):

You can execute any Java, Scala, Python or R code in your Spark applications and can therefore use any of the common SMB libraries available for these languages.

For example the following Python snippet using the pysmb library will work in Spark as well:

```
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection

username = "..."
password = "..."
client_name = "..."
server_name = "..."
server_ip = "..."
share_name = "..."

conn = SMBConnection(username, password, client_name, server_name, use_ntlm_v2 = True)
assert conn.connect(server_ip, 139)

for f in conn.listPath(share_name, "."):
  print(f.filename)
```

The code will be executed directly on the driver so you can't really use this approach for massive amounts of data but for smaller files it's a completely viable option. You can first read the files into driver memory and then parallelize them so that they can be joined with your other datasets.

Comment: The answer should minimally address how to use the file paths within spark.

Answer (score -2):

```
     String user = "username";
     String password = "password";
     String path = "smb://cluster14/g/SNBFIle.xlsx";
     NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new 
     NtlmPasswordAuthentication("",user,password);
     SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(path, auth);

    InputStream is = smbFile.getInputStream();
File targetFile = new File("test/resources/data/file.xlsx");
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(is, targetFile);
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(targetFile);
        for(Sheet sheet : workbook) {
            String sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
            System.out.println(sheetName);
            Dataset<Row> excelDataSet =
                dataLoaderContext.getSparkSession().read()
                    .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
                    .option("dataAddress", sheetName.trim() + "!A1")
                    .option("header", "true")
                    .option("useHeader", "true")
                    .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
                    .option("addColorColumns", "false")`enter code here`
                    .load("test/resources/data/file.xlsx");
            datasetList.add(excelDataSet);

        }
         datasetList.forEach(dataset -> System.out.println(dataset.count()));
```

Comment: Please add imports and sources for jar files.
This code copies smb file, then runs spark on the one file.
This example doesn't show how to use 'within' spark, to use the distributed nature of spark to access the files in a SMB share.